# Node.js w/ express error handling in callback

Tags: node.js, express

I'm new to node.js and express. I have the following in my app.js file as a last resort error handler:

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
  // we may use properties of the error object
  // here and next(err) appropriately, or if
  // we possibly recovered from the error, simply next().
  res.status(err.status || 500);

  console.log(err);

  var errMsg = "An internal error occurred. Please notify your system administrator.";

  // respond with json
  if (req.accepts('json')) {
    res.send({error: errMsg});
    return;
  }

  // respond with html page
  if (req.accepts('html')) {
    res.render('500', errMsg);
    return;
  }

  res.type('txt').send(errMsg);
});
```

It works for me during testing when I kill the database server or otherwise induce a 'middleware' level error, but I'm not sure if it will also kick in when a callback receives an error? I've been using something like this inside my callbacks:

```
if(err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.send(500, {error: err});
}
```

but I'd like to better adhere to the DRY principle and figure out a way to handle errors inside callbacks globally (across modules) instead of writing a bunch of the same code. If the middleware 'catchall' won't work, am I stuck with a global function per module? Hope this make sense.

Comment: indeed it seems error-middleware doesn't catch errors in callbacks...

Answer (score 1):

Look at [connect-domain](https://github.com/baryshev/connect-domain) middleware. It helps you to catch all errors inside of asynchronous callbacks, timeouts, etc. Works only with node > 0.8.0.

Comment: The domain feature seems to be the way things are going in Node for this type of thing, but I'm not sure it's ready for production use. Checkout this discussion involving the creator of connect/express:

https://github.com/visionmedia/express/issues/1291

Answer (score 1):

For now I ended up just creating a global error handler module:

```
exports.globalErrorHandler = function(err, req, res) {
  if(!err || !req || !res) return;

  console.log(err);

  var errMsg = "An internal error occurred. Please notify your system administrator.";

  // respond with json
  if (req.accepts('json')) {
    res.send({error: errMsg});
    return;
  }

  // respond with html page
  if (req.accepts('html')) {
    res.render('500', errMsg);
    return;
  }

  res.type('txt').send(errMsg);
}
```

and requiring it in the modules that need it:

```
var gh = require('../helpers/globalErrorHandler.js');

// Inside a callback
if(err) {
    gh.globalErrorHandler(err, req, res);
    return;
}
```

Comment: Are you still using app.use with this?